# Draw text and image on a UIView or UIImageView?

Tags: uiview, overriding, draw

I need to draw some text and some images(Escape character) on a View(UIView, UIImageView or whatever).I know override Draw method, or take a CGContext to generate a CGImage. But I don't know how to bring about code. Can someone give me an example. Especially how to get the position when last component is drawn. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a UILabel, and add it to the UIView?